# Swift PDFKit highlight

Tags: swift, highlight, pdfkit

How do I interact with the Highlight button using PDFKit? I'm not able to highlight the selected text when I press the Highlight.

[image]

```
struct PDFTestView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let document: PDFDocument
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = document
        pdfView.scaleFactor = 0.55
        pdfView.autoScales = true
        
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PDFView, context: Context) {
            addHighlight(view: uiView)
    }
    
    func addHighlight(view: PDFView) {
        guard let selections = view.currentSelection?.selectionsByLine() else { return }
        
        selections.forEach { selection in
            selection.pages.forEach { page in
                let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: selection.bounds(for: page), forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
                highlight.color = .yellow
                page.addAnnotation(highlight)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm only able to highlight the selected text if I add a button to toggle a bool property to true.

```
struct PDFTestView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let document: PDFDocument
    @Binding var isHighlight: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = document
        pdfView.scaleFactor = 0.55
        pdfView.autoScales = true

        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PDFView, context: Context) {
        if isHighlight { // <--- isHighlight toggled
            addHighlight(view: uiView)
        }
    }

    func addHighlight(view: PDFView) {
        guard let selections = view.currentSelection?.selectionsByLine() else { return }

        selections.forEach { selection in
            selection.pages.forEach { page in
                let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: selection.bounds(for: page), forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
                highlight.color = .yellow
                page.addAnnotation(highlight)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.